# Sorting out a vector by smallest number first, doing the exact same opposite?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to make this vector/object sorter all day and even if I exchange the signs (< and >) nothing seems to be happening. I have integers randomly put in a random order and the objective for the program is to sort them by size. I have sketched it out on a paper to get a better overview but when I try to sort it out from lowest to highest in a descending order, it seems to do it from highest to lowest. I hope the Swedish in the code won't disturb.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                for (int a = i; a < 25; a++)
                {
                    int ettan = price[i];
                    int tvåan = price[a];
                    if (ettan > tvåan)
                    {
                        dryck tmp = new dryck(null, 0, null);
                        tmp = drycker[i];
                        drycker[i] = drycker[a];
                        drycker[a] = tmp;
                        continue;
                    }

                }

            }
```

EDIT: Forgot to add, it's supposed to compare the first integer [0] with [1] [2] and so on, until it has found one that is lower than [i], and then exchange them with eachother, so the lower integer is placed in the first spot etc.

Comment: The thing is, I have separate vectors for the drinks' name, price and beverage type and then I have one for all of them combined, which is "drycker" which then would be able to contain ("Fanta", 15, "Soda") for example, and I don't think the separate vectors interferes with the result at all, but if you could disapprove that, I would be happy, because I don't know what is wrong. And it seems means that it does, don't know why I wrote that.

Comment: Can you provide input, expected output and actual output for a reasonable sample size?  Have you stepped through to see where things are going wrong?

Comment: Well the ideal output would be if I put in a Fanta that costs 20, a Cola that costs 15 and a Sprite that costs 17, that the output would be with the Cola on top, the sprite second and the Fanta on the bottom, but it does the exact opposite.

Comment: Is there anything after the if statement which would necessitate the `continue`?

Comment: I don't really need that, I think, but when I first put it there, the inner for loop felt like it didn't loop as it would be supposed to do. That's another story though.

Comment: Maybe I'm just stuck... But have you tried changing the prices the same way as you change 'drycker'? If it works I'll tell you why :)

Comment: Goddamnit, thank you Jibbow! It worked with swapping the prices along with the vectors, but could you explain why?

Comment: Type it as an answer so I can mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the `vectors` in C# are called `Arrays` ;-)

In a nutshell you are comparing products with the wrong prices. But why? Let me show this with an example:

There are two important arrays:

```
drycker:               Prices:
 Cola          ->         25
 Fanta         ->         20
 Sprite        ->         30
```

When you compare Cola with Fanta the new lists look like:

```
drycker:               Prices:
 Fanta         ->         25     -> the price for Fanta is now 25
 Cola          ->         20
 Sprite        ->         30
```

The point is that you are comparing the products with their positions and you change the product, but not its price. Answer: Change the prices, too, in order to keep the Arrays consistent.

---

Other suggestions:

Maybe one Array (`drycker`) is enough (depends on the code). Then you could compare it directly:

```
if( ((dryck) drycker[i]).price > ((dryck) drycker[a]).price)
```

Or you could use Linq with a List:

```
List<dryck> drycker = new List<dryck>(); //strongly typed lists are always recommended
drycker.Sort(x => x.price);
```

The last suggestions probably contains some new stuff for you. You could search for `List`, `Linq` and `Lambda expressions` to go a little deeper. But this is just the "high quality" solution :)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do it manually, without any predetermined sorter. Thank you man!